# Converting Line Breaks from a Flex property file in an Array

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I have a Flex 4.5 AS3 app where I am calling a Flex Property file that contains \n line breaks. Those line breaks are showing up in the message box inside of the Array.

Here is the text from the property file:
Click "Yes" to save the Activity.\n\nPlease Note: \n\n* The activity status will be "Draft" and can not be viewed outside your post until it is "Approved".\n\n*

Here is the call.

```
var new_message:String = properties.getProperty("config.messages.activity.actionsave");
```

Comment: You should provide a little more information, nobody knows about your code. What message box are you talking about and how is it invoked, and what does an array have to do with it? Also have you tested that `new_message` really contains the expected chars?

Comment: Here is the answer:
    var new_message:String = properties.getProperty("config.messages.activity.actionsave").replace(/\\n/g, "\n");

Comment: please add your comment as an answer - and then mark it as answered